# OOB based question for Python, am I miss understanding something?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have created a class and am attempting to run multiple instances of that class.

I have a dataset that is shared amounst the count of instances.

For each data set an instance is started with the relevant data added to the args.

Now the problem I am having is that the data set being used by each instance ends up being the data set that is last passed into the final instance.

```
#Generate Arguments and logger (info)
args, info = general.arg_checks()

threads = []

args2 = args  #FIX ADD

#Check Browser Range, if there is more than one
if args.browsers > 1:

    # send data to data splitting function (this splits data perfectly)
    data_set = general.browser_set(args.data, args.browsers) 

    count = len(data_set)

    #Start MultiBrowser
    try:
        # Iterate the list of data sets, for each set run an instance and pass that data into the args.
        for data in data_set:

            args2.data = data # FIX ADD

            #Initiatiate Instance
            job = worker._generate(args, info)

            #Create thread of instance
            thread = threading.Thread(target=job.job_start, args=(str(count),))

            threads.append(thread)

            count -= 1

        #Start each thread
        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()

    except TypeError:
        pass

    except Exception as e:
        self.info(e, exc_info=True) 


else:
    #Start Single Browser
    count = 1
    job = worker._generate(args, info)
    job.job_start(str(count))
```

Comment: "I have a dataset', "For each data set". Soo... how many data sets are we talking about? Is it a universal one like you say in line two or a separate one for each instance?

Comment: It starts as one set, then it is split into various sets depending on the 'args.browsers' value. If its 4 the set is split into 4 (as equil as possible) parts

Comment: Don't use the same `args` object when creating each `job`.

Comment: @Barmar that is the question yes. If you notice Im placing an args into each instance of the class. So in my mind it shouldnt be the same args, that is the point of this question

Comment: So create a new `args` object each time through the `for` loop.

Comment: @Barmar I was under the impression I was, but after your comment I took another look. I created a copy of the initial one and updated the relevant args values on each iteration. Going to do more specific testing but I think that should have done the trick.

Comment: Python does not create a new object when you assign a new name to it, you must do that yourself by explicitly making a copy. Otherwise all the references will share the same object.

Comment: @MarkRansom lesson learnt, thanks all